# DELETE operation returns ERROR: There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). Forbidden

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am working on a **spring-boot** project which includes **thymeleaf**, **spring-security**. It works fine when I perform - showing products-list, showing products-details, adding new product, updating existing product.

But when I perform - deleting an product, it gives the following ERROR:

> **Whitelabel Error Page**
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Jul 18 16:59:16 BDT 2019
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
>
> Forbidden

Here is my code:

**product_list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Product List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Product List</h1>
            <hr>
            <a class="btn btn-success" th:href="@{/products/add}">Create New Product</a>
            <hr>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Brand</th>
                        <th>Made In</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="theProduct:${theProducts}">
                        <td th:text="${theProduct.id}">Product ID</td>
                        <td th:text="${theProduct.name}">Name</td>
                        <td th:text="${theProduct.brand}">Brand</td>
                        <td th:text="${theProduct.madein}">Made In</td>
                        <td th:text="${theProduct.price}">Price</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-info" th:href="@{'/products/show/' + ${theProduct.id}}">View</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-warning" th:href="@{'/products/edit/' + ${theProduct.id}}">Edit</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" th:data-the-product-id="${theProduct.id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirmationModal">Delete</a>
                            
                            <div class="modal fade" id="deleteConfirmationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteConfirmationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                    Are you sure you want to DELETE the Product.
                                    <br>
                                    <form id="deleteForm" action="#" th:method="DELETE">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Employee</button>
                                    </form>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script th:src="@{/js/jquery-3.3.1.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/popper.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>
        <script>
        $('#deleteConfirmationModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var anchorLink = $(event.relatedTarget)
            var theProductId = anchorLink.data('theProductId')
            var modal = $(this)
            $("#deleteForm").attr("action", "/products/delete/" + theProductId)
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ProductController.java**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.example.demo.dao.ProductRepository;
import com.example.demo.entity.Product;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model theModel) {
        List<Product> theProducts = productRepository.findAll();
        theModel.addAttribute("theProducts", theProducts);
        return "product/product_list";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String add(Model theModel) {
        Product theProduct = new Product();
        theModel.addAttribute("theProduct", theProduct);
        return "product/product_add_form";
    }

    @GetMapping("/show/{productId}")
    public String show(@PathVariable int productId, Model theModel) {
        Product theProduct = productRepository.findById(productId).get();
        if(theProduct == null) {
            return null;
        }
        theModel.addAttribute("theProduct", theProduct);
        return "product/product_detail";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("theProduct") Product theProduct) {
        theProduct.setId(0);
        productRepository.save(theProduct);
        return "redirect:/products/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/edit/{productId}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable(name="productId") int productId, Model theModel) {
        Product theProduct = productRepository.findById(productId).get();
        theModel.addAttribute("theProduct", theProduct);
        return "product/product_edit_form";
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute("theProduct") Product theProduct) {
        productRepository.save(theProduct);
        return "redirect:/products/index";
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{productId}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable int productId) {
        Product tempProduct = productRepository.findById(productId).get();
        if(tempProduct == null) {
            return null;
        }
        productRepository.deleteById(productId);
        return "redirect:/products/index";
    }
}
```

**LoginController.java**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login"; 
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model theModel) {    
        return "redirect:/products/index";  
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(users.username("admin").password("Admin.123").roles("EMPLOYEE", "ADMIN"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**")
            .permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fortunately you add "modal" inside thymeleaf each loop, so edit your html from according my code ....

```
 <form id="deleteForm" th:action="${'/products/delete/' + theProductId}" th:method="DELETE">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Employee</button>
 </form>
```

this is tested code ...working fine ..
**you just miss "th:action" for that it dose not work as thymeleaf form. so thymeleaf dose not provide hidden "_csrf" field;**

Comment: Thanks it worked. Actually I added `th:action="${'/products/delete/' + theProductId}"` at the beginning. But I did something wrong in JavaScript and then removed `th:action`. And then solved the JavaScript problem but forgot to add the `th:action` :p

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling `csrf` token in your configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

Comment: you are right.... i test his code .....but csrf is very important for security reason .... even for testing purpose